# how to use XMLHttpRequest ajax request data in bootstrap table

Tags: marketing-cloud, javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap

How can i use XMLHttpRequest ajax request data in bootstrap table. Below is my code where i am doing a ajax call by javascript.

I want to display the data in bootstrap table on page load.

Can anyone help me out.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
    <button id="button">Create Table!</button>
</div>

<script>
 var getTableDataAJAX = function() {

    var getTableData = new XMLHttpRequest();

    getTableData.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(getTableData.readyState === 4) {
            var tableInfo     = JSON.parse(getTableData.responseText);
            console.log(tableInfo);
            var tableHeading  = tableInfo.Email_Address;
        };
    };
    getTableData.open("GET", "https://members.s7.exacttarget.com/Pages/Page.aspx?QS=38dfbe491fab00ea3e13562977897afc1a710dc71c13e7ad973c5bb1d2d232f7&brand_code=PE&email_address=huntcyber@gmail.com", true);
    getTableData.send();
};

var wrapperDiv = document.querySelector('div');
var AJAXbutton = document.getElementById('button');

AJAXbutton.addEventListener('click', getTableDataAJAX);   
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Below is the array which is getting created which i can see in console.

```
Email_Address:"huntcyber@gmail.com"
```

HTML -

```
<table data-classes="table table-condensed"
                data-toggle="table"
    data-url=""
    data-select-item-name="subscriber_key"
    data-id-field="Newsletter_SubKey"
    data-click-to-select="true"
    data-buttons-align="right"
    data-show-columns="true"
    data-toolbar="#toolbar"
    data-toolbar-align="left"
    data-search="true"
    data-pagination="true"
    data-show-pagination-switch="true"
    >
    <thead>
    <tr>

                                <th data-field="Email_Address" data-sortable="true" data-visible="true" data-title-tooltip="Newsletter_Master: Email_Address">Email</th>

                </tr>
                </thead>
</table>
```

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Thats a pure javascript question. You only need to get data from `tableInfo`. If you could post the html code you have tried so far then I can help you.

Comment: How to pass the tableinfo into data-url of bootstrap..

Comment: There is mismatch in table columns and data you are receiving. Table has State and Email address but ajax data has date and email

Comment: I have updated the code. There are a lots of field. So just i have updated the code with one filed. Rest i will take care. Thanks/

Answer (score 1):

This how we add row in a table:-

First I have given ID (myTable) to the table to reference it in javascript.

```
<table id="myTable" data-classes="table table-condensed"
                data-toggle="table"
    data-url=""
    data-select-item-name="subscriber_key"
    data-id-field="Newsletter_SubKey"
    data-click-to-select="true"
    data-buttons-align="right"
    data-show-columns="true"
    data-toolbar="#toolbar"
    data-toolbar-align="left"
    data-search="true"
    data-pagination="true"
    data-show-pagination-switch="true"
    >
    <thead>
    <tr>

                                <th data-field="Email_Address" data-sortable="true" data-visible="true" data-title-tooltip="Newsletter_Master: Email_Address">Email</th>

                </tr>
                </thead>
</table>
```

Javascript snippet (go through comments to understand what it does):-

```
getTableData.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(getTableData.readyState === 4) {
            var tableInfo     = JSON.parse(getTableData.responseText);
            console.log(tableInfo);
            var tableHeading  = tableInfo.Email_Address;

            var tableRef = document.getElementById('myTable');

            // Insert a row in the table at row at last index 
            var newRow   = tableRef.insertRow(tableRef.rows.length);

            // Insert a cell in the row at index 0
            var newCell  = newRow.insertCell(0);

            // Append a text node to the cell
            var newText  = document.createTextNode(tableHeading);

            newCell.appendChild(newText);
        };
    };
```

Above solution should be enough for you to achieve further things by making some changes here and there.

Comment: I am getting an error .. Page.aspx?QS=5c591a8…:29 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'insertRow' of null...at line ... var newRow   = tableRef.insertRow(tableRef.rows.length);

Comment: Did you add ID "myTable" to the table? make sure the code is present before calling the ajax request. @learningmode